# Filepath.Walk in Go not picking up folders under C: drive properly in Windows

Tags: windows, go, filepath

I am using the Filepath.Walk in Go to try to get all the folders under C: recursively. However it just returns me sub-folders starting with $Recycle.Bin. What am I doing wrong here?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    array := Subfolders("C:")
    for _,value := range array {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}

func Subfolders(path string) (paths []string) {
    filepath.Walk(path, func(newPath string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            paths = append(paths, newPath)
        }
        return nil
    })  
    return paths
}

Output:
C:
C:\$Recycle.Bin
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$R0L9M20
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$R22ZOD9
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$R3LS9P4
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$R4T2IGU
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$R8TZIET
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$R9QQZB9
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$RA71HY3
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$RBOC0V4.com
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$RBOC0V4.com\go-fsnotify
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$REJFS3Z
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$RF9A1Y6
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$ROMESWQ
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$RP4CYID
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$RQHMPV5
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$RV0K99H
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-310629982-3373693989-3733510080-1000\$RX54T04
```

I have many other folders under C: which donot get picked up by the filepath.walk. I wanted to understand what was the reason behind it.

EDIT

---

Thanks to the answers I was able to resolve the issue as below:-

```
func Subfolders(path string) (paths []string) {
    filepath.Walk(path, func(newPath string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return filepath.SkipDir
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            paths = append(paths, newPath)
        }
        return nil
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're blindly returning errors without logging them. Returning a non-`nil` error from the callback is a signal for `filepath.Walk` to abort.

Presumably there is some file you don't have access to, or something.

Comment: This makes complete sense. A rookie mistake. Thankyou for pointing it out. I need to learn more about error handling in Go.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning an error, so it stops walking the paths. As [the spec](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#WalkFunc) states, whenever an error is returned (besides one special case), processing stops. If you'd like to continue processing and ignore the error, just `return nil` instead.

Running it on my machine gives me an `Access is denied` error on one file, which then nukes the walk. The reason is only sees `$Recycle.Bin` is because it happens to be the first folder in the directory, and the walk is killed before it can get to any others.